# TDD/testing CSS and HTML

Tags: python, html, css, django, tdd

I am stuck at this point below:

'''selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .has-error'''

I tried to find a solution related to ".has-error" in order to get one of the functional tests via TDD to pass. Anyone ever experienced being stuck with that? Am I doing something wrong or missing a very little point? Your help would be appreciated!

Related code between my template/selenium:

Python part:

```
self.wait_for(lambda: self.assertEqual(self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.has-error').text,
            "You can't have an empty list item"))
```

html part:

```
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                </div>
     {% endif %}
```

Comment: I've had that error before but it's really hard to help unless you post some code. You should post the related code from your template and selenium

Comment: @Brenden I inserted two coding parts above. Lmk if you are able to give feedback. I appreciate your response earlier.

Comment: I think this should work: self.wait_for(lambda: self.assertEqual(self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-group.has-error').text , let me know how it goes. Oh, and I am unsure why what you originally had isn't working sorry, I'm also confused

Comment: @Brenden thank you for your response! I tried your suggestion but it still doesnt work. I have been doing chapter 13 of TDD book, so here is the link: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_database_layer_validation.html and look for .has-error. This is what I have been trying to solve at this point.

Comment: I worked through that book a few weeks ago. I don't remember having difficulty with that part. I did however have difficulty with the exact same thing the other day on my own website. I has trying to use find_element_by_css_selector to select an object that had two classes and couldn't get it to work (i ended up getting it to work by adding both classes like this: ('.form-group.has-error')). There's definitely something there which is catching both of us. I hope you figure it out or someone else can help you on here - I'd appreciate it too

Comment: Thank you again for your reply - I tried this twice but it still doesnt work. I am still figuring out at this point but I think I will let this skip. I am afraid if I let it do so, I will end up receiving errors or failing continuously. Also I researched CSS selector, so I think I understand more of it. But this kind of error is still unsolvable. Curious - did you ever use html linter plugin? One guy from another forum mentioned he used it.